# Find a pattern starting from a specific line of file

Tags: bash

I want to find a pattern starting from a specific line rather than from the beginning and then delete all the lines starting from this specific position to the point/line where the pattern was first matched.

Comment: Is the specific line a number that doesn't change (i.e. on the tenth line always)?

Answer (score 1):

This will delete starting from line 10 until the pattern is matched:

```
sed '10,/pattern/d' file > newfile
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
sed -e "$lineno,/$pattern/d" $file
```

where

- `$lineno` is your line number for start deleting
- `$pattern` is your pattern
- `$file` is your file